# Is there a way to preserve the RGB values of a pixel with an Alpha different from 255 in a PNG?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rgb, alpha

I'm currently working on a project that envolves working with PNGs that have custom RGBA values. This is a preview of the code I use to create a PNG `NSData` that contains my custom RGBA values (all of this is working as it should):

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixelData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, BytesPerRow, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx);
NSBitmapImageRep *newRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage];
NSData *pngData = [newRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
```

When I'm creating the `pixelData` (which is an `uint8_t` array that contains all the RGBA values) and I set the `Alpha` index of each pixel as 255, the `int` values of each R/G/B of each pixel are the same when I was creating them.
Here's an RGBA example (`Alpha` = 255) -> **(72, 101, 114, 255)**
Now, if I set the `Alpha` of all pixels to be, let's say, 100, instead of 255, the above RGBA example will look like: **(184, 255, 255, 100)**.
As you can see, the RGB values are totally different from what I created initially, and I really need to preserve the original values (through a custom property when creating the `NSData` or something like that) or a way to calculate them back, no matter what the `Alpha` value is. Is there any way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `kCGImageAlphaLast` instead of `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`. Whatever you're doing to change the alpha is premultiplying for you: 184 = 72 * (255 / 100).  The other two values are getting clipped at 255.

Comment: tried using `kCGImageAlphaLast` but now it gives me an error and no image is created. More details here: http://pastebin.com/SRde1HP7

Comment: Yes, `kCGImageAlphaLast` is not in the list of [supported pixel formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) for bitmap graphics contexts.

Comment: Would running once with no alpha and again with alpha premultiplied last be an acceptable workaround? It'd be a double decode but what are you trying to optimise for — effort, speed, code size, what?

Answer (score 0):

Your data has un-premultiplied (by alpha) color components. Core Graphics is expecting premultiplied alpha.

Depending on how your build your `pixelData` array, you can either pre-multiply it in your own code as you go (e.g. `premultipliedRed = unpremultipliedRed * alpha / 255.0`) or you can use the Accelerate framework to convert it after the fact. You would use the function `vImagePremultiplyData_RGBA8888()` to do that:

```
vImage_Buffer buffer = { pixelData, width, height, BytesPerRow };
vImagePremultiplyData_RGBA8888(&buffer, &buffer, 0);
```

If, later, you get back premultiplied data and you need to convert back to un-premultiplied, you can do the reverse using `vImageUnpremultiplyData_RGBA8888()`. There may be some loss of precision in the round trip, so you're not absolutely guaranteed to get back the original source data bit-for-bit. It's an inevitable consequence of converting between unpremultiplied and premultiplied. If that's a problem, you need to keep the original source data or not use Core Graphics.